# Парсинг instagram

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, requests, beautiful-soup

Как я могу получить все ссылки на публикации аккаунта в инстаграме?
Пробовал через bs4, requests, selenium, все это с headers'ами В html одно и тоже и нет нужного, как будто js блокирует или что-то типа того. Подскажите в какую сторону думать? Такая проблема именно с сайтом инстаграмма.

Answer (score 1):

Есть прекрасный запрос, который возвращает кучу данных о пользователе(включая информацию о последних 15 постах). А там уже можно будет покопаться с bs4 и работой со словарями.

```
'https://instagram.com/zuck/?__a=1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать instagram api. Есть несколько модулей для пайтона. Так же вот, что можно найти в документации [про получение постов](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/)

Так же, возможно, стоит обратить внимание на [этот репозиторий](https://github.com/pgrimaud/instagram-user-feed)

Comment: На сколько я знаю, апи у инстаграма ограниченное, пока они тебе его не одобрят. А в ограниченной версии можно было только 20 последних постов получить, по крайней мере раньше. Да, и посты мне нужны не со своего аккаунта.

Comment: @ClarkDevlin так как в коде страницы нет всех постов, думаю, единственных выход это имитация бразуера через requests или selenuim, как удобно тебе

Comment: я понимаю, но когда я получаю html файл с помощью этих библиотек там совершенно не то, что в браузере. В коде посты есть, если через браузер смотреть, во вложенных дивах.